# Groovy XMLParser - update node text

Tags: xml, groovy

I have some XML file, and I want to change *name*, if *name == testName*. So I wrote something like this, but it doesn't work. Where I have done a mistake? It prints to me argument type mismatch, and I don't know why.

```
String xmlData = "
    <logger>
      <logLevel>
        <id>1</id>
        <idn>id1</idn>
        <name>testName</name>
        <level>warn</level>
        <logLevelsPos>
          <package id="97724539">
            <packName>package1</packName>
          </package>
          <package id="98264591">
            <packName>package2</packName>
          </package>
        </logLevelsPos>
      </logLevel>
      <logLevel>
        <id>2</id>
        <idn>id2</idn>
        <name>nameName</name>
        <level>error</level>
        <logLevelsPos>
          <package id="12732539">
            <packName>package2</packName>
          </package>
          <package id="43264591">
            <packName>package5</packName>
          </package>
        </logLevelsPos>
      </logLevel>
    </logger>";

def loggr = new groovy.util.XmlParser().parseText( xmlData );
for (def it : loggr.children()){
    if(it.name.text().equals("testName") ) {
        it.name.value = "ds";
        //argument type mismatch ...
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you have to access the value of the text-node within `name`.  so it is `it.name[0].value = 'ds'`

Comment: Oh.. i was close :) But why [0]? Don't understand

Comment: Hmm.. understand: because it's a list wich consists of 1 element

Comment: In this case one.  There could be more.